# Styling upper triangular, lower triangular, and diagonal of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have generated a pandas dataframe and I want to use `pd.DataFrame().style` to highlight some cells.

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
v1  0   1   1   1   0
v2  0   0   1   1   1
v3  0   0   0   0   0
v4  0   0   0   0   0
v5  0   0   0   0   0
```

I want to color its upper and lower triangular, as well as its diagonal. To do so I'm doing the following:

1. Compute lower and upper triangular, and diagonal.

   ```
   def triang(df):
       temp=df.copy()
       ut=np.triu(np.ones(df.shape),1).astype(np.bool)
       lt=np.tril(np.ones(df.shape),-1).astype(np.bool)

       temp=temp.where(ut==False, 'up')
       temp=temp.where(lt==False, 'lt')
       np.fill_diagonal(temp.values,'dg')
       return(temp)

   triang(mymat)
   ```

returns

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
v1  dg  up  up  up  up
v2  lt  dg  up  up  up
v3  lt  lt  dg  up  up
v4  lt  lt  lt  dg  up
v5  lt  lt  lt  lt  dg
```

2. Define the color function

   ```
   def color_vals(value):
        if value == 'up':
            color='orange'
        elif value=='lt':
            color='blue'
        else:
            color='black'
        return(color)
   color_vals('up')
   #'orange'
   ```
3. Style the dataframe

   ```
   triang(mymat).style.applymap(color_vals)
   #returns the same as triang(mymat)
   ```

I am stuck in the style part (step 3). I'd like to see the very first matrix (`mymat`, the one with `0` and `1`) stylized according to the colors per section (upper, lower triangular and diagonal).

How can I do the last step?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, try this:

where df_vals:

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
v1   0   1   1   1   0
v2   0   0   1   1   1
v3   0   0   0   0   0
v4   0   0   0   0   0
v5   0   0   0   0   0

def triang(df):
    temp=df.copy()
    ut=np.triu(np.ones(df.shape),1).astype(np.bool)
    lt=np.tril(np.ones(df.shape),-1).astype(np.bool)

    temp=temp.where(ut==False, 'up')
    temp=temp.where(lt==False, 'lt')
    np.fill_diagonal(temp.values,'dg')
    return(temp)

def color_vals(val):
    """
    Color dataframe using values
    """
    d = {'up' : 'orange',
         'dg' : 'black',
         'lt' : 'blue'}
    return [f'color : {i}' for i in triang(df_vals).loc[val.name, val.index].map(d).tolist()] 

df_vals.style.apply(color_vals)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you so much. However, I would like to see the initial matrix that contains `0` and `1` with these colors. Appologies if I didnt explain myself well, I'll edit my post

Comment: Ah... okay.  I think I understand.

Comment: @Sosi  It took me a bit to get back to working on this.

Comment: No problem at all Scott, thank you I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to see the very first matrix (mymat, the one with 0 and 1) stylized according to the colors per section (upper, lower triangular and diagonal)

Okay so you can modify the function like below:

```
def myfunc(x):
    c1=np.triu(np.ones(df.shape),1).astype(np.bool)
    c2=np.tril(np.ones(df.shape),-1).astype(np.bool)
    col1='color:orange'
    col2='color:blue'
    col3='color:black'
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.select([c1,c2],[col1,col2],col3),columns=x.columns,index=x.index)
    return df1
```

---

```
df.style.apply(myfunc,axis=None) # mymat.style.apply(myfunc,axis=None)
```

---

[image]